# How can i play my script on Dockerfile and pass argument to the script

Tags: linux, docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I have this Dockerfile , i want to pass argument to the script and run it on the container and for some reason it wont work.
i use ARG & ENV and ENTRYPOINT.

```
FROM jrei/systemd-ubuntu:18.04
MAINTAINER devops@carbyne911.com
RUN apt-get update -y && \
  apt-get upgrade -y  && \
  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  vim \
  apt-utils \
  net-tools \
  openjdk-8-jre \
  linux-headers-generic \
  libgstreamer1.0-0 \
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good \
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad \
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly \
  gstreamer1.0-libav \
  gstreamer1.0-doc \
  gstreamer1.0-tools \
  gstreamer1.0-rtsp \
  python-gst-1.0 \
  python3-gst-1.0 \
  libgstreamer1.0-dev \
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \
  libfontconfig1-dev \
  libfreetype6-dev \
  libpng-dev \
  libcairo2-dev \
  libjpeg-dev \
  libgif-dev \
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev 
ARG JAR_VERSION
ENV mfsVersion=$JAR_VERSION
RUN mkdir -p /home/ubuntu
COPY ./target/deployment/dependencies.tar.gz /home/ubuntu
COPY ./target/deployment/aws_install-docker.sh /home/ubuntu
COPY ./target/deployment/MediaForwardService-${JAR_VERSION}-standalone.jar /home/ubuntu
COPY ./target/deployment/MediaForwardService-${JAR_VERSION}-standalone.jar /home/ubuntu
COPY ./target/deployment/libMediaForwardRSL-${JAR_VERSION}.so /lib64/
COPY ./src/main/resources/application.conf /home/ubuntu
COPY ./target/deployment/systemctl3.py /usr/bin/systemctl
RUN test -L /bin/systemctl || ln -sf /usr/bin/systemctl /bin/systemctl
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/systemctl
WORKDIR /home/ubuntu
RUN chmod +x aws_install-docker.sh
EXPOSE 8102
EXPOSE 16384 
EXPOSE 32766
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","-c", "/home/ubuntu/aws_install-docker.sh"]
CMD ["$mfsVersion"]
```

It seems that i have mistake with the argument that i passing. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: You probably want no `ENTRYPOINT` but just `CMD ./aws_install-docker.sh $mfsVersion`, at a guess, but without the actual error message it's a little hard to say.

Comment: What are you using Windows or Linux? The [[tag:cmd]] tag suggests the command interpreter for Windows, but your code suggests you're doing this in Ubuntu and using the `B`ourne `A`gain `SH`ell. As this does not appear to be for Windows command interpreter, `cmd.exe`, and you've had ample time to respond, I have decided to remove your invalid tag.

Answer (score 0):

In your setup, the argument that you have in your `CMD` is passed as an argument to `/bin/bash` and not to your script, so it will actually run:

`/bin/bash -c /home/ubuntu/aws_install-docker.sh $mfsVersion`

instead of

`/bin/bash -c "/home/ubuntu/aws_install-docker.sh $mfsVersion"`

What you need to do, is remove the `CMD` and provide the arguments in the `ENTRYPOINT`.

So you can use:

`ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash -c "/home/ubuntu/aws_install-docker.sh $mfsVersion"`

but, unless you have a special reason for using `/bin/bash -c`, I would simply do:

`ENTRYPOINT /home/ubuntu/aws_install-docker.sh $mfsVersion`

Here is a simpler Dockerfile for experimenation:

```
FROM alpine
ARG JAR_VERSION="1.0"
ENV mfsVersion=$JAR_VERSION
ENTRYPOINT echo $mfsVersion
```

which can be built and ran by:

```
$ docker build -t temp --build-arg JAR_VERSION=2.0 .
$ docker run --rm -it temp
2.0
```

Lastly, depending on your needs, you might want to use either `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` for that task (but not both). Here is an example using an entrypoint script (instead of plain `echo`) and in the `CMD` instead of the `ENTRYPOINT`:

```
FROM alpine
ARG JAR_VERSION="1.0"
ENV mfsVersion=$JAR_VERSION
COPY ./entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint
CMD /entrypoint $mfsVersion
```

and the `entrypoint` sample script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo "Params: $*"
```

The advantage of using the `CMD` for this, is that you can still enter into the container using `docker run image-name bash` when needed.